# How to Create Datetime get set in class of Georgian type as my System is in Hijri format?

Tags: c#, asp.net, class, datetime, date-format

I am passing Object to method. Object has many data including date in this format `2018-10-10` Getting object in method,

```
public void GetPerformanceReport(Criteria Cri)
{
...
}
```

Criteria is class having exact same data withvariables.

```
    public class Criteria 
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the city.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>The city.</value>
        public Datetime? From{ get; set; }
        public Datetime? To { get; set; }
}
```

Now issue is that my system is in hijri calender date come to method but criteria class das datetime getset that does not understand it due to hijri calender and gives me null value.

How to make Dstetime in class of georgian type so that i will get date passing to method

Edited:

My View is like,

```
                    <div class="col-md-9 ">
                        <div class="input-group input-group-unstyled">
                            <input ng-if="::!$root.isRtl" name="startDate" type="text" class="form-control" ng-class="{'ng-invalid': !vm.isValidRange}"
                                   ng-model="vm.searchCriteria.startDate"
                                   ng-change="vm.validateDateRange()"
                                   calendartype="gregorian"
                                   language="en"
                                   dateformat="yyyy-mm-dd"
                                   showonfocus="true"
                                   kdatepicker
                                   hidden="hidden" readonly required />
                            <input ng-if="::$root.isRtl" name="startDate" type="text" class="form-control" ng-class="{'ng-invalid': !vm.isValidRange}"
                                   ng-model="vm.searchCriteria.startDate"
                                   ng-change="vm.validateDateRange()"
                                   calendartype="gregorian"
                                   language="ar-EG"
                                   dateformat="yyyy-mm-dd"
                                   showonfocus="true"
                                   kdatepicker
                                   hidden="hidden" readonly required />
                            <span class="input-group-addon">
                                <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                    <label class="col-md-3 control-label">
                        {{ 'EndDate' | translate }}
                        <span ng-show="criteriaForm.endDate.$invalid">
                            <span ng-show="criteriaForm.endDate.$error.required">*</span>
                        </span>
                    </label>
                    <div class="col-md-9 ">
                        <div class="input-group input-group-unstyled">
                            <input ng-if="::!$root.isRtl" name="endDate" type="text" class="form-control" ng-class="{'ng-invalid': !vm.isValidRange}"
                                   ng-model="vm.searchCriteria.endDate"
                                   ng-change="vm.validateDateRange()"
                                   calendartype="gregorian"
                                   language="en"
                                   dateformat="yyyy-mm-dd"
                                   showonfocus="true"
                                   kdatepicker
                                   hidden="hidden" readonly required />
                            <input ng-if="::$root.isRtl" name="endDate" type="text" class="form-control" ng-class="{'ng-invalid': !vm.isValidRange}"
                                   ng-model="vm.searchCriteria.endDate"
                                   ng-change="vm.validateDateRange()"
                                   calendartype="gregorian"
                                   language="ar-EG"
                                   dateformat="yyyy-mm-dd"
                                   showonfocus="true"
                                   kdatepicker
                                   hidden="hidden" readonly required />
                            <span class="input-group-addon">
                                <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                            </span>
                        </div>
```

IN js i am using search function that is,

```
$scope.search = function (page) {
    if (!$scope.SearchReport.$valid) {
        toastr.error(FillAllRequired);
        return;
    }
    if (page != undefined) {
        $scope.page = page;
    }
    evaluationsService.getPerformanceReport($scope.searchCriteria, ($scope.page * $scope.pageSize), $scope.pageSize, $scope.sortBy, $scope.sortingDirection).then(onGetPerformanceReportSuccess, onError);}
```

On methos GetPerformanceReport it is like

```
   public JsonResult GetPerformanceReport(PerformanceReportSearchCriteria searchCriteria)
        {}
```

PerformanceReportSearchCriteria  is a class that is,

```
 public class PerformanceReportSearchCriteria
    {
public DateTime? From { get; set; }
 public DateTime? To { get; set; }
}
```

IN get Performance report i am getting Null for From and To date ??

Comment: Post the code that returns `null`. DateTime has no format. Formats apply only when parsing strings or generating strings. The calendar doesn't affect how the strings are parsed or generated. It affects date calculations.

Comment: Getters and setters simply set or return a property's value anyway, they don't parse, understand, or modify the values in any way. If you get a `null` it means that either the value was never set, or it was set to `null`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos i edited post how and where i am getting Null value

Comment: you haven't posted any C# that sets properties, just class definitions and an empty method. Are you sure your *Javascript* code sends a full request? Does `$scope.searchCriteria` contain the dates? This is most likely a binding problem.

Comment: Does `searchCriteria` contain properties named `From` and `To`? The `input` tags in your view bind to `startDate` and `endDate` properties, eg ` ng-model="vm.searchCriteria.endDate`. ASP.NET MVC can't guess that `From` and `To` map to `startDate` and `endDate`. You should probably rename the properties to `FromDate` and `StartDate`

Answer (score -1):

Try following which converts the xml string to your datetime

```
    public class Criteria
    {
        private DateTime from { get; set; }
        private DateTime to { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the city.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>The city.</value>
        public string From { 
            get { 
                return from.ToString("yyyy-mm-dd");
            }

            set { 
                from = DateTime.ParseExact("yyyy-mm-dd",value, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            }
        }
       public string To {
           get {
               return to.ToString("yyyy-mm-dd");
           }

            set { 
                to = DateTime.ParseExact("yyyy-mm-dd",value, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What XML string? The OP's code shows Angular code posting to an MVC action

Comment: The view is a string.  I should of said html instead of xml, sorry.

Comment: if you check the view's code you'll see the inputs bind to viewmodel properties named `startDate` and `endDate`, not `From` and `To`. `DateTime.Parse` can handle `yyyy-MM-dd`. I suspect the property names are just wrong

Comment: Even if code like this *is* required (which I'd really hope it isn't) it should definitely use `MM` rather than `mm`.